# Equally distributing values among a pyspark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark data frame

for example, I have a user table like below

```
users    col1  col2  col3
1      A      AA   AAA
1      A      AA   AAA
2      A      AB   AAB
3      A      AA   AAA
4      A      AA   AAA
6      B      BB   BBB
7      B      BB   BBB
8      A      AA   AAA
```

and a cost table dataframe like below

```
col1 col2 col3 cost
A     AA   AAA   1000
A     AB   AAB   200
B     BB   BBB   420
```

I need to distribute this cost among the users equally. Like below and I need the final output column like below

Result column

```
users    col1  col2  col3   cost 
1      A      AA   AAA      200
1      A      AA   AAA      200
2      A      AB   AAB      200
3      A      AA   AAA      250
4      A      AA   AAA      200
6      B      BB   BBB      210
7      B      BB   BBB      210
8      A      AA   AAA      200
```

How can I do it with pysaprk data frame: This is the example dataset. My column size of users is around 1GB and Cost table is around 10 Mb. I am new to pyspark what is the best way to tackle this problem?

Update: It needs row count updated the example data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working solution for you

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, broadcast, col
user.join(broadcast(user.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3")\
    .agg(count("users").alias("count"))\
    .join(broadcast(cost), ["col1", "col2", "col3"])\
    .withColumn('cost', col('cost')/col('count'))), ["col1", "col2", "col3"])\
    .drop('count')\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|col1|col2|col3|users|cost |
+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|A   |AA  |AAA |1    |250.0|
|A   |AB  |AAB |2    |200.0|
|A   |AA  |AAA |3    |250.0|
|A   |AA  |AAA |4    |250.0|
|B   |BB  |BBB |6    |210.0|
|B   |BB  |BBB |7    |210.0|
|A   |AA  |AAA |8    |250.0|
+----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

**Explaining:**

There are three parts in the above solution

the first part is the aggregation

```
user.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3")\
    .agg(count("users").alias("count"))
```

which gives you

```
+----+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|col3|count|
+----+----+----+-----+
|A   |AB  |AAB |1    |
|B   |BB  |BBB |2    |
|A   |AA  |AAA |4    |
+----+----+----+-----+
```

the second is the *first join* ( I have used `broadcast` function as you said the *cost dataframe is small*)

```
user.groupBy("col1", "col2", "col3") \
    .agg(count("users").alias("count")) \
    .join(broadcast(cost), ["col1", "col2", "col3"]) \
    .withColumn('cost', col('cost')/col('count'))
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|col1|col2|col3|count|cost |
+----+----+----+-----+-----+
|A   |AB  |AAB |1    |200.0|
|B   |BB  |BBB |2    |210.0|
|A   |AA  |AAA |4    |250.0|
+----+----+----+-----+-----+
```

And the *last is the joining of above output with the user dataframe*. And *dropping the extra count column*

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks, @Ramesh. It is very helpful

Comment: If the same user is a present duplicate. I want to include them also like

1      A      AA   AAA
1      A      AA   AAA

If present two times. I need to count it as two. I need a row count instead of distinct count @Ramesh

Comment: the solution is counting them as two. did you test before you leave a comment ? @utp